# automatic validation does not appear when adding functionality to submit

Tags: jquery, validation, window, submit, onload

i have script like this, (using jquery.validate.js)

**input.php**

```
<?php
if ($input=='inputform'){
echo $_POST[username].'-'.$_POST[email];
}
?>
```

**form.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            remote: "users.action"
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: "emails.action"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "enter your name",
            minlength: jQuery.format("enter at least {0} character"),
            remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
        },
        email: {
            required: "enter your email",
            minlength: "enter your email",
            remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
        }
    }
}); 

//automatic validation does not appear when users type in error. It happens when I make a submit function like this. 
$("#sign").CheckAndSubmit(function()
    {         
        window.onload {
        document.getElementById('signupform').submit();
    }
    }); 

 });
</script>

<form id="signupform" action="input.php?input=inputform" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckAndSubmit()">
        <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Name</td>
            <td><input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" maxlength="50" /></td>
            <td class="status"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Email</label></td>
            <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /></td>
            <td class="status"></td>
    </tr>
    </table><table>     
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Order"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i hope automated validation appear and submission process run. is there someone who can help this problem in this section. thank you before

```
$("#sign").CheckAndSubmit(function()
    {         
        window.onload {
        document.getElementById('signupform').submit();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

because calling submit using script will not trigger the click event. So try

```
$('#signupform').submit();
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('signupform').submit();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4mAdr/)

Note: There are other syntax errors in your script & the submit button with name `submit` will override the form method `submit` which will prevent the `form.submit()` call so rename the button.

Comment: yes sir, it is true there is no error in my script, but how that could be automated validation and submit work as it should work well. because when I give the submit function, automatic validation does not work

Comment: did you try my answer by replacing the submit function

Comment: yes i have tried it, how that he release the results as expected on input.php ?

Comment: @ivanichi in that case `$("#sign").click(function () {
        if ($('#signupform').valid()) {
            $('#signupform')[0].submit();
        }
    });
` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4mAdr/5/